# Apache returning private IP in 301 response over http1.0

Tags: apache, http

During a nikto scan, we found that Apache (or so it appears) returns the servers private IP during a 301 redirect to https. I was able to reproduce it by a simple curl:

```
curl http://example.com/ --http1.0 --header 'Accept:' --header 'Connection:' --header 'Host:'
```

Which returns:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
 <html><head>
 <title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
 </head><body>
 <h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
 <p>The document has moved <a href="https://PRIVATEIP/">here</a>.</p>
 </body></html>
```

Although I have now identified the issue, resources are fairly limited on how to overcome this and the Nikto documentatation refers to this as an IIS 7 bug.

From what I can see, our options are either trying to fix this or not allow http1.0

**Fixing it:**

Following this very old recommendation (https://securitytracker.com/id/1002188) I can confirm that the ServerName is set to the servers hostname and that UseCanonicalName does not even appear in the http.conf file but looking at Apache documentation the default is anyways Off. I have also changed the /etc/hosts file to have the hostname refer to 127.0.0.1 but still no change. I simply dont know where or why the IP is present in the 301 redirect response.

**Disabling http1.0**

For the particular site, I have modified the Apache conf to:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} HTTP/1\.0$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Yet, there appears to be no difference when I do a new curl request or run nikto again.

Any ideas would be awesome as I've spent the better part of the day trying to solve this :)

Comment: Does that same curl request, but with http1.1, result in correct redirect?

Comment: @DusanBajic when I attempt 1.1 the server returns a 400 Bad Request

Comment: Well, your rule for blocking http1.0 is correct, so it is either placed in wrong conf file or virtual host, or you did not enable mod_rewrite (make sure you have `RewriteEngine On` in your .conf). About private IP in redirect, are you sure that apache is sending this redirect, maybe it is coming from your webapp?